# Difference between declaring and initializes

Tags: c#, .net, windows, runtime, c#-6.0

I'm very new to C# and to programming in general, and there is something I am wondering about the difference between simply declaring something vs initializing.
For example, if I use `String.Split()` method, in the documentation it says that it returns an array with the delimited characters, but why can I not access that array? I have to do something like:

```
string [] array = mystring.Split()
```

Is there a way to work with something that has only been declared but not initialized? What happens during runtime with things that have only been declared (variables, arrays, etc.)?
Thank you.

Comment: You can indeed access that array. What's your mean. Your question is unclear.

Comment: You can access that array without assigning the result directly: `foreach (string word in "some words".Split()) { Console.WriteLine(word); }`

Comment: You cannot use a variable that has not been initialized, however - you'll get a compile error like `"Use of unassigned local variable"` or something like that. But I don't see what that has to do with your question.

Comment: `string first = myString.Split()[0]` works just fine too.  You only need to assign the return of `Split()` to a variable if you want to use it later (99.9% of the time you will want to use it later)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare a variable by stating it's type and name:

```
string[] array;
```

You initialize it by giving it it's initial value:

```
string[] array; // declare
array = mystring.Split(); // initialize
```

In c#, as in many other programming languages, you can combine both actions into a single code line:

```
string[] array = mystring.Split();
```

When you do that with local variables, consider using [`var`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) instead of explicitly using the type of the variable in the declaration, but only in cases where the type of the variable can be easily deduced from the right hand side of the assignment operator:

```
var list = new List<int>(); // best.

var array = mystring.Split(); // still quite good.

var myVar = SomeClass.SomeMethodThatWeDoNotKnow(); // not so good...
```

The reasoning for this is that it's obvious to everyone reading the code that `list` of a `List<int>`, while you have to know what string.Split returns to know that `array` is an array of strings, and you need to actually hover the mouse over the `var` keyword to know what type is `myVar`.

When declaring fields (meaning - class level variables), they are automatically initialized with [their default value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table) - `null` for reference types, `0` for numbers, etc'. However, this default value rule does not apply to local variables (meaning - variables declared inside a method) or to method arguments - You have to explicitly initialize them before you can use them, otherwise you'll get a compilation error:

```
int a;
Console.Write(a);
```

Will yield this compilation error:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'a'

Whenever you use a method that returns something (meaning, it's not [`void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/void)), you can use whatever that method is returning directly, without setting the result into a variable:

```
if(myString.Split()[0] == someSubString) // use a value from the array
{ /* do some stuff here */ }

var result = SomeClass.Method().ToString(); // use ToString on the return value of Method
```

or just simply ignore the return value if you don't need it:

```
// Just an example, don't do that with TryParse!
int i;
int.TryParse(s, out i); // if fails, i will be initialized to it's default value - 0

// do some other stuff
```

Comment: Thank you for your in depth answer. I may have not asked my question correctly, so let me give a concrete example.
If I write the code <br>
string test = "Hello";<br>
test.Split();<br>
Console.WriteLine(test[0]);<br>
It works and it puts out the letter "H" to screen! I was previously confused because I didn't know I could call the array in a separate line. Now what I am wondering is what happens when the computer runs the test.Split() line. It actually runs it, and it seems to put the array into memory. Is that correct? Do all returned objects from methods work this way?

Comment: I'm not really sure that's going on under the hood, does it really matter? You could probably look at the compiled code (but then you'll need to learn the MSIL to understand what's going on there, and that's only another level of abstraction over the machine code, so it might not give you the answer you are looking for)

Answer (score 0):

why can I not access that array?

You can, you don't have to put the result into a variable:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(mystring.Split()[0]); //will print the value of index 0. This is dangerous.
```

Is there a way to work with something that has only been declared but not initialized?

You can check if what's declared is null if its a reference object, so technically, that is working with it before its initialized. Value types are initialized to a default when declared. You can declare some types and look at the values assigned in the debugger:

```
int four; //0
double two; //0
string[] fizbo; //null
object food; //null
```

What happens during runtime with things that have only been declared?

You should read about what happens when you declare an object and what happens when you declare a reference type.

See: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76153/Six-important-NET-concepts-Stack-heap-value-types

Comment: If a local reference type is declared but not assigned, it will **not** be `null`, *you will get a compile time error*. Local value types like you have in your example are **not** initialized when you declare them. On the next line try writing `Console.WriteLine(four);` and see what the compiler says...

Comment: [stack, heap, who cares?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/) (This is the guy you want to read from, trust me)